# ElasticSearch 6.5.4 takes long time to start - over 1h

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch set up with one node called master.
Logs are stored on HDD for the last 10 days - 130GB.

When I restart ElasticSearch it takes over 1h to start:

```
[2020-08-22T13:14:56,338][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [master] initialized
[2020-08-22T13:14:56,338][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [master] starting ...
```

...

```
[2020-08-22T13:15:02,628][INFO ][c.f.s.c.IndexBaseConfigurationRepository] [master] Check if searchguard index exists ...
[2020-08-22T13:15:02,628][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.e.i.TransportIndicesExistsAction] [master] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2020-08-22T13:15:05,675][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [master] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {master}{HgUjRVxxxxxxxxx}{F8puntj7Qi98m8aSQTxut9ug}{serverxxxxx}{145.183.205.172:9300}{ml.machine_memory=34359201792, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
```

...

```
[2020-08-22T13:15:05,800][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [master] started
[2020-08-22T13:15:05,800][INFO ][c.f.s.SearchGuardPlugin  ] [master] 0 Search Guard modules loaded so far: []
[2020-08-22T13:15:07,208][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)
[2020-08-22T13:15:08,228][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)
[2020-08-22T13:15:09,205][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)
```

....
final message after 1h when it all starts working (Gurad module is set up properly and  it works fine, not sure why the )

```
[2020-08-22T14:26:36,032][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [master] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[searchguard][0], [heartbeat-6.5.4-2019.09.02][0], [metricbeat-6.5.4-2019.09.03][0], [metricbeat-6.5.4-2019.09.02][0]] ...]).
```

Is this normal behavior because of the logs size?

Update: After search guard logs level change to Debug I see many messages from Safe guard with index names for specific dates

```
[2020-08-28T21:52:00,720][DEBUG][c.f.s.c.IndexBaseConfigurationRepository] [master] index 'searchguard' not healthy yet, we try again ... (Reason: timeout)
[2020-08-28T21:52:00,782][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)
[2020-08-28T21:52:00,844][DEBUG][c.f.s.SearchGuardPlugin  ] [master] Handle complianceConfig=null/dlsFlsAvailable: false/auditLog=class com.floragunn.searchguard.auditlog.NullAuditLog for onIndexModule() of index services.poc.core.webapi-microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.exceptionhandlermiddleware-2020.08.28
[2020-08-28T21:52:01,282][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)
[2020-08-28T21:52:01,282][DEBUG][c.f.s.SearchGuardPlugin  ] [master] Handle complianceConfig=null/dlsFlsAvailable: false/auditLog=class com.floragunn.searchguard.auditlog.NullAuditLog for onIndexModule() of index services.test.ioi.webapi-test.services.dataservices.premservice-2020.08.28
[2020-08-28T21:52:01,724][DEBUG][c.f.s.SearchGuardPlugin  ] [master] Handle complianceConfig=null/dlsFlsAvailable: false/auditLog=class com.floragunn.searchguard.auditlog.NullAuditLog for onIndexModule() of index services.test.pusher.service-microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.forbidresult-2020.08.28
```

Update: the issue might be large number of indexes
GET /_cat/indices
Response is around 2000 indexes

Comment: It's definitly not normal. 
your cluster have a problem. Usualy it's because of lack or RAM / Processors. But it can come from elsewhere. In the few logs lines you provided, it's strange to see searchguard with xpack enabled, and 0 Search Guard modules loaded so far. Could your issue become from a not perfect removing of searchguard plugin ?

Comment: Its big machine 16CPUs and 32GB RAM. Cpu is all the time under 20% while starting and ram is actually 8GB as this is min max setting. I've changed RAM setting to large value but I've rolled it back as per ElasticSearch doc recommendation is 4GB -8GB and to have min max value the same.

Comment: About memory. You should have misunderstood something. 
Memory of your JVM should be 50% or less of the total RAM available in your OS. In your case you could set min/max to 16GB. (max for 1 node is around 31GB for Java reasons). did you investigate on the searchguard logs ?

Comment: Safe Guard level is set to debug and I can see many messages from Safe Guard and specific indexes

Comment: It looks like my issue is common to this one: https://forum.search-guard.com/t/search-guard-doing-compliance-check-for-each-index-causing-huge-delay-in-es-restart/1689/22

Comment: Yes I think so. If you find the solution, can you close the ticket please ?